# flutter sqlite query makes null column into null string

Tags: sqlite, flutter

In the sqlite table i have null columns. I made a query to get all data from specific column and map its data into `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = List();
final db = await database;
var result = await db.query('tools_table', where: 'LifeCycle <> 2');
result.forEach((val) {
  maps.add(val);
});
```

but null column converted into the "null" and when i want to deserialize list of map into object :

```
ToolsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
...
    if (json['triggerImagesUrl'] != null) {
      triggerImagesUrl = List<String>();
      var job = jsonDecode(json['triggerImagesUrl']);
      job.forEach((v) {
        triggerImagesUrl.add(v);
      });
    }
```

I got error because json['TriggerUrl'] is nut null, it is "null" and `var job = jsonDecode(json['TriggerUrl']);` job be a null and job.forEach cause e exception.

Why null column is converted to the "null" and how can i prevent of this action ?

Comment: Can you share the schema and the insertion query?

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fM7X32PPKb/ @snj

Comment: Is TriggerUrl changed to TriggerImagesUrl?

Comment: yes i changed @snj

Comment: please share JSON response too. It can also be the issue

Comment: It is returnd from database @snj

Comment: Can u share the definition of mapToCacheActivatedToolItem and did u try to extract the db from the mobile and analyze the stored data?

Comment: This is https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qfxqqgkswn/ and yes i extract the db and everything was ok and all null data are stored @snj

Comment: I don't see any issue in jsonEnocode and jsonDecode. Can you share sqldump?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wkIxnoMG21j4S7eaFYL0BEwLr6pt8jaF  @snj

Comment: So I tried to extract the sql dump and found the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213007/discussion-between-snj-and-sayres-kabir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in dart pad

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
void main() {
  List<String> urls = null;
  var d = jsonEncode(urls);
  print(d  is String);
  print(jsonDecode(d) is String);
}
```

You'll get following output

```
true
false
```

So `jsonEncode(urls)` returns `null` string if `urls` is null.
Change this

```dart
Map<String, Object> mapToCacheActivatedToolItem(LogData.Data item) {
    var newMap = {
      "TriggerImagesUrl": item.triggerImagesUrl == null ? null : jsonEncode(urls)
    };
    return newMap;
  }
```